# When using "git pull" operation, It will result in a new log which display "Merge remote branch into local branch"

Tags: git, git-branch

When using "git pull" operation, It will result in a new log which display "Merge  remote branch into local branch". The log just look like as follow:

```
SHA-1: 3c4e93220199713ac4ad4695b93ea1d4f7f821fc
* Merge branch 'feature/hub' of http://tfs.bg.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/gitProject into feature/hub
```

Can anyone tell me why? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If you pull in changes from a remote repository, Git by default creates merge commits if you pull in divergent changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pull` is a shortcut for `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.

First, `http://tfs.bg.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/gitProject` is fetched, probably to your local ref `<remote_name>/feature/hub`.

Then, the fetched commits are merged into your current local branch (the one you have checked out, probably `feature/hub`): your remote branch is merged to your local branch.

This works even if you have made local changes in `feature/branches`, it gets the commits from the remote and merges them together with your local changes, and update `feature/hub` with the result.

Comment: Can I change the merge display tips?

Comment: You could always redirect the output if you don't want to see it: `git pull > /dev/null`, but I can't really see why you'd want to hide it.

Comment: I just want to see the team members actual commits without the default merge commit, Because my team which has 11 members operate the same git project  frequently. @Gauthier

Comment: Oh, you mean the commit message for the merge commits? You could always edit the text after it is created with `git commit --amend`, but the text is standard and ok. Or do you mean that you would like to get rid of the merge commits altogether?

Answer (score 1):

That's what *pull* command does. It gets all the commits (that are not in the local repo yet) made from the remote repo to the local repo, then it merges the changes.